# Check if website can be viewed without getting blocked by firewalls

Tags: web, firewall, blocked

How can I check if website can be viewed without getting blocked by firewalls like the ones in the schools or in the public places?

I want my website to possibly be viewed from everywhere.

I have Cloudflare DNS and an SSL Certificate from Let's Encrypt

Thank you!

I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have only the best intentions with this

I first want to point out, that there are many different scenarios of your site to get blacklisted/blocked. Which would reach from a school blacklisting you to a government DNS blocking your website.

In contrast there would be whitelisting e.g. the school deciding that the people in their network only can view this list of websites. In this case you could do very little to be reached from this network.

To circumvent the blockage of a website it normally requires the user to get around it e.g. by using a VPN.

That said, it seems to me that for a new site it would be most effective to not get blacklisted in the first place.

Comment: I only wanted to know because I published a website for my classroom mates that could help they doing tasks (anything that is not admitted, obviously). The last time we went to the computer science lab the website was locked, I think because it's a newly registered domain.

Comment: In that case i would recommend a VPN. You could also self host that. VPNs are normally blocked in schools, but that's not so hard to bypass. In your school you could try to ping the public ip of your server, if that's possible you could reach the website by typing the ip in your browser. In which case you'll maybe have to edit your webserver config.

Comment: Oh i missed the part with the science lab computers, so you will probably not have the eights to connect to a VPN there.